# Accessing a WordPress Database from a mobile app

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have a WordPress website with custom tables that I store data into that was entered by customers. The site owner wants to develop a barcode app that can  access this data.  When *I* need the data from these fields to display within the site,  I request it from a PHP script running on the server that make calls like `get_post_meta()`.

The owner has hired a mobile app consultant who believes that, if he just has the password to the account where the site is hosted,  he can access all of these database fields from the app.

I'm not seeing how this is possible. My understanding is that a mobile app can only access a site by making HTTP requests to it. It has no way of running on the server and executing things  like `get_post_meta()`.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean 'custom tables'?  get_post_meta() pulls data from the wp_postmeta table which is a standard wordpress table.

Comment: You're right.  I meant custom fields in the standard wp_postmeta table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing something.  Wordpress now has a rest api https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ that can allow a mobile application get at data in your database by making http requests.

The developer will need to be able to enable the Rest Api, but if you give her the password, she will probably be able to do so.  Typically this is done using a plugin like: [WP Rest API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) which enables a set of [default endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/) which includes post meta data and allows you to [add other endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/)

Depending on how the custom tables are set up, they might not be automatically available to the Rest API.  However, if you are able to access them using get_post_meta() then I would expect that they would be accessible to the Rest API as well, most likely by [adding endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/).

Comment: _"Depending on how the custom tables are set up, they might not be available to the Rest API."_  Are you saying that, without me writing any code on the server, the mobile app could make a REST request to an endoint that already exists in WordPress that could fetch database fields?

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't able to find the "default endpoints," though from your link to them.

Comment: If you follow that link you will see a sidebar on the left.  Each item in that sidebar (e.g. Post) is an example of a core Wordpress resource.  If you click it, you will see a sidebar on the right that contains and example data endpoint in the form of a curl request to that endpoint.  By clicking through all of the items in the left sidebar you can see all of the "default endpoints" and how to access them.